# Line spacing not applying when using <li> tag

Tags: html, cpq, style, design-attributes

This is for Salesforce CPQ Template Content. I have a spacing issue when using the li tag. If the item is too long and is forced onto more than one line, it doesn't take into account the style="margin-..." attribute. I need uniformed spacing between all list items whether they are one line or multiple lines per item, but do not know how to achieve this.[image: Spacing Issue]

Answer (score 0):

You can apply css class on ordered or unordered list to make list item's height of same size.

```
ul li {
  line-height:30px
}
```

Comment: I've used 
<style type="text/css">ul li {
  line-height:30px
}
</style>
but it only applies to the first line of each list item and not the second if there is a newline for that list item.

Comment: It will work for all list items. See example https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4QLLDDD1FNW. If not then please share sample like this so that i can check and help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up faking the listed items inside a padded table.

Comment: This should be added to the question itself - can you please edit your question to include the fact that it's about CPQ? You can also add a note in the question that the padded table was your workaround, but it's not really an "answer" to your question. Thanks!